# Showing ajax content in same page without page load

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My ajax_form.php page is:

```
<html><head>
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
<script>
function showUser(form, e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var xmlhttp;
 var submit = form.getElementsByClassName('submit')[0];
 var sent = document.getElementsByName('sent')[0].value || '';
 var id = document.getElementsByName('id')[0].value || '';


if (sent==""){
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
}

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(e) {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open(form.method, form.action, true);
xmlhttp.send('sent='+sent+'&id='+id+'&'+submit.name+'='+submit.value);
}
</script>

<form action="ajax_test.php" method="POST">
Enter the sentence: <input type="text" name="sent"><br>
<input type="submit" class="submit" name="insert" value="submit" onsubmit="showUser(this, event)">
</form>

<br>UPDATE <br>

<form action="ajax_test.php" method="POST" onsubmit="showUser(this, event)">
<pre>
    Enter the ID : <input type="text" name="id"><br>
    Enter the sentence: <input type="text" name="sent"><br>
</pre>
 <input type="submit" class="submit" value="submit" name="update" >
</form> <br>
<div id="txtHint">
 <b>Person info will be listed here.</b>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

and ajax_test.php is:

```
<html><head>
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
</head> <body > 
<?php
// $q = $_POST["q"];
// you never process the $q var so i commented it
if (isset($_POST['insert']) && $_POST['insert'] !== '') {
echo "Operation: Insert","<br>";

$s = $_POST['sent'];

$flag = 0;

echo "Entered sentence : $s";

if (preg_match_all('/[^=]*=([^;@]*)/', 
    shell_exec("/home/technoworld/Videos/LinSocket/client '$s'"),
    $matches)){ //Values stored in ma. 
    $x = (int) $matches[1][0]; //optionally cast to int
    $y = (int) $matches[1][1];
}

echo "<br>",
     "Positive count :$x",
     "<br>",
     "Negative count :$y",
     "<br>";

//---------------DB stuff --------------------
$con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1:3306', 'root', 'root', 'test');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO table2 
         (id,sent,pcount,ncount,flag)
         VALUES
         ('','".$_POST['sent']."',' $x ','$y','$flag')";
if (mysqli_query($con, $sql1)) {
   echo "1 record added";
} else {
   die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}


mysqli_close($con);
}

// -------------------------------UPDATE --------------------------
 if (isset($_POST['update']) && $_POST['update'] !== '') {
echo "Operation: update", "<br>";
 // you say update but you are actually inserting below

$s    = $_POST['sent'];
$flag = 1;

echo "Entered sentence : $s";

if (preg_match_all('/[^=]*=([^;@]*)/', 
    shell_exec("/home/technoworld/Videos/LinSocket/client '$s'"),
    $matches)) //Values stored in ma.
{
    $x = (int) $matches[1][0]; //optionally cast to int
    $y = (int) $matches[1][1];
}

echo "<br>",
     "Positive count :$x",
     "<br>",
     "Negative count :$y",
     "<br>";

//---------------DB stuff --------------------
$con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1:3306', 'root', 'root', 'test');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO table2 
         (id,sent,pcount,ncount,flag)
         VALUES
         ('','".$_POST['sent']."',' $x ','$y','$flag')"; // error here again $_POST[id] should be $_POST['id'] with quotes
if (mysqli_query($con, $sql1)) {
  echo "1 record added";
} else { 
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

 mysqli_close($con);
}
?></html > </body >
```

In form1 I have put function call on button click event, which works fine. But on button click it load the page and redirects to ajax_test.php. can we say it proper use of ajax?

In second form I have kept function call in form itself and coded as required in script. But on button click on action takes place. Is it wrong function call or any other mistake?

How can I show result without page load(refresh) in both cases?

Comment: @StevenMoseley: Sorry buddy, i signed off for some time! Let me check it!

Comment: You don't use IE by chance? There you might need a e.returnValue=false instead of the e.preventDefault(). Another reason to use libraries like jQuery which hide a lot of the browser incompatibilities. It would simplify your code as well.

Comment: @mvw: thanks,I wish  `        e.preventDefault();
        e.returnValue=false;` will not create problem even for IE too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `sent` parameter - it's looking for an input named "sent", which doesn't exist.  And then, if it's not set, it's exiting the `showUser` function.

Here's the offending snippet (which I removed below):

```
if (sent==""){
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
}
```

In addition to that problem, you also had no close `</head>` or open `<body>` tags, which in themselves are not the problem, but a pretty major formatting issue.  Also, always put a `type` on your `<script>` element.  Finally, you should close `<meta />`, `<input />` and `<br />` elements inline. Formatting your code consistently (sibling elements on their own lines, 4-space tabs for each heirarchical level) helps you find little formatting issues like the missing open body, etc.

That said, this works for me:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function showUser(form, e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var xmlhttp;
        var submit = form.getElementsByClassName('submit')[0];
        var sent = document.getElementsByName('sent')[0].value || '';
        var id = document.getElementsByName('id')[0].value || '';

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open(form.method, form.action, true);
        xmlhttp.send('sent=' + sent + '&id=' + id + '&' + submit.name + '=' + submit.value);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="ajax_test.php" method="POST" onsubmit="showUser(this, event)">
        <label>Enter the sentence: <input type="text" name="sent"></label><br />
        <input type="submit" class="submit" name="insert" value="submit" onsubmit="showUser(this, event)" />
    </form>

    <h4>UPDATE</h4>
    <form action="ajax_test.php" method="POST" onsubmit="showUser(this, event)">
        <pre>
            <label>Enter the ID:</label>
            <input type="text" name="id"><br>
            <label>Enter the sentence:</label>
            <input type="text" name="sent"><br>
        </pre>
        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="submit" name="update" />
    </form>

    <br />
    <div id="txtHint">
        <b>Person info will be listed here.</b>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, I learnt atleast how to code.
But my problem still persist. It shows nothing once I click on the button.

Comment: Try using a debugger like Firebug for Firefox. It helps you to find out what is going on, what works and where things go wrong. Set a breakpoint in the Ajax response handler to check if you get what you expect by the Ajax call. Use break points around the innerHTML to see if you update the DOM with what you expect.

Comment: And the network tab allows you to inspect the Ajax request and response.